# Shell Script for Flip Canvas Vertical

Tags: shell, canvas, vertical-alignment, flip

I have M1.jpg M2.jpg ....... M100.jpg in /Users/KanZ/Desktop/Project/Test/ 
I would like Flip Canvas Vertical them, save and replace them instead of old files. How can I write the script for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with [convert](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_convert.htm), with a little help from [find](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_find.htm) so you don't have to write a loop:

```
find /Users/KanZ/Desktop/Project/Test/ -type f -name "M*.jpg" -exec convert {} -flip {} \;
```

**Explanation:**

- `find /Users/KanZ/Desktop/Project/Test/` - Invoke `find` tool and specify the base directory to perform the search for files recursively.
- `-type f` - Find only files
- `-name "M*.jpg"` - Find only files with names that start with `M` and end with `.jpg`
- `-exec ... \;` - For each such file found, perform the command in `...`
- `convert {} -flip {}` - This is the actual command that flips your images. The `{}`'s are syntax as part of the `find` command, they represent where the found files from `find` would be substituted into. So here we are saying to use `convert` to flip the images vertically with the `-flip` option, but keep the file names unchanged.

**Alternatively:**

You can also do it with a loop and globbing:

```
for file in /Users/KanZ/Desktop/Project/Test/M*.jpg; do convert "$file" -flip "$file"; done
```

Comment: It's not work. It can't find a file or directory with this code

Comment: @kantawit you may have specified the wrong directory path in either your question or on your cmdline - it's working for me.

Comment: I type like this 
for file in /Users/KanZ/Desktop/Project/Test/M*.jpg;
do convert "$file"
-flip "$file";
done

Comment: @kantawit that means you need to install `convert` first =) If you are on ubuntu, just do `sudo apt-get install convert`

Comment: It tell me that find: convert: No such file or directory. I type this code in one line.Is it right?

Comment: @kantawit what system are you on?

Comment: @kantawit Looks like it's actually part of ImageMagick - Try following  the install instructions here: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php#unix

Comment: I try to write the flip image code as Shell Script in order to adapt it to use flip the image with automatically every time before I run my Apps.

Comment: @kantawit This is shell script. `convert` is a tool accessible to shell once you install it.

Comment: Now I test the script on Mac by run the script before compile the Xcode. So how can I write code for Shell Script to flip the image in directory and add this script into xcode so that xcode can run the script before compile the xcode.

Comment: @kantawit This IS the shell script for your original question. You'll want to ask a separate question for using it as part of XCode

Comment: can you tell me step by step how to install in order to use your code